# React - как вывести результаты get запроса в html список?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

У меня есть такой ответ от сервера:

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "test_result": {
        "passed": [
            {
                "test": "app.test.test_auth.MyTest.test_success"
            }
        ],
        "errors": [
            {
                "test": "app.test.test_auth.MyTest.test_error",
                "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"C:\\Users\\Asus\\PycharmProjects\\app\\test\\test_auth.py\", line 15, in test_error\n    self.assertEqual(1 / 0, 1)\nZeroDivisionError: division by zero\n"
            }
        ],
        "failures": [
            {
                "test": "app.test.test_auth.MyTest.test_fail",
                "traceback": null
            }
        ],
        "skipped": []
    }
}
```

И такой код приложения:

```
class Test extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            status: '',
            test_result: {}
        };
        this.handleCLick = this.handleCLick.bind(this)
    }

    handleCLick() {
        axios.put('http://localhost:8000/sc')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({status: response.data.status});
                this.setState({test_result: response.data.test_result});
                })
    }

    render(){

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleCLick}>Start</button>
                <p>{this.state.status}</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        {this.state.test_result}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Как вывести test из каждого элемента? Никак не могу разобраться с ключами

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
const { passed, errors, failures, skipped } = this.state.test_result;   

const renderItems = obj => {        
    return obj.map(({ test, traceback }, i) => {
        return (
            <div key={i}>
                <p>test: {test}</p>
                {traceback && <p>traceback: {traceback}</p>}
            </div>
        );
    });
};

return (
    <div>  
        {renderItems(passed)}
        {renderItems(errors)}
        {renderItems(failures)}
        {renderItems(skipped)}
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

так тоже работает:

```
{[passed, errors, failures, skipped].map(obj=> renderItems(obj)  )}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пишет, что TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: нужно посмотреть какая структура объекта, приходящего с сервера и что записывается в state.  Использовать console.log.   У меня этот код работает.

Comment: Я в итоге убрала доп вложенность в test_result, т.е. теперь у меня приходит сразу:
`{'status': 'fail',
   "passed": [
            {
                "test": "test_success"
            }
        ],
    "errors": [
            {
                "test": test_error",
                "traceback": "Traceback "
            }
        ]}`

В state пишется так:
 `this.state = {
            status: '',
            errors: []
        };`

Comment: В setState:
`this.setState({errors: response.data.errors});`

Ваш код я поместила в render, и в связи с новой структурой ответа поменяла только эту строку: `const { errors } = this.state.errors;` , и вывод только `{renderItems(errors)}`

И вот правильно ли я вообще все поменяла?

Comment: В state в выводе в render() лежит:

`Object
status: ""
errors: Array(0)
length: 0`

и ошибка TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: после строчки `const { passed, errors, failures, skipped } = this.state.test_result; ` добавить `console.log(passed, errors, failures, skipped )`   . Если что либо из этого не массив будет ошибка